# How do I link an azure service bus publisher opentelemetry span to subscriber trace in another process using .net core c#

Tags: .net, azure, service, bus, open-telemetry

I have 2 processes running

webapi : publishes message to azure service bus queue

console app: subscribes to message from queue

I am using open telemetry collector with yaeger, .net core 6, c#

I am able to see traces from the .net core webapi that publishes to the queue in yaeger

I am also able to see traces from the .net core console app subscriber in yaeger.

However, I do not see the spans from the subscriber in the webapi trace. Not sure what I am missing. Trying to link the subscriber trace/span to the parent webapi trace so that I can see a complete trace.

I followed these links
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/introducing-experimental-opentelemetry-support-in-the-azure-sdk-for-net/ and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-end-to-end-tracing?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2

I do see the Diagnostic-Id come across on the subscriber, not able to link it to the trace coming from the publisher webapi

Any advice appreciated.

======== Otel Setup Code on subscriber console app =======

````
        static async Task Main()
        {
            AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);
            AppContext.SetSwitch("Azure.Experimental.EnableActivitySource", true);

            //--------------  Tracing --------------------
            var env = "Development";
            var applicationName = "ConsoleAppQueueProcessor";
            var assemblyVersion = Assembly
                .GetExecutingAssembly()
                .GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyFileVersionAttribute>()!
                .Version;

            meter = Measures.GetMeter(Measures.InstrumentationName);
            ConsoleAppQueueProcessorCounter = meter.CreateCounter<int>("ConsoleAppQueueProcessor");



            using var openTelemetry = Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
                .SetResourceBuilder(
                    ResourceBuilder
                        .CreateDefault()
                        //.CreateEmpty()
                        .AddService(serviceName: applicationName, serviceVersion: applicationName)
                        .AddAttributes(
                            new KeyValuePair<string, object>[]
                            {
                                new("deployment.environment",env),
                                new("host.name", Environment.MachineName),
                                new("application.name", applicationName),
                                new("application.assemblyversion",assemblyVersion)
                            })
                        .AddEnvironmentVariableDetector() //Set using powershell: $env:OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES = 'key1=value1,key2=value2'
                )

                .SetSampler(new AlwaysOnSampler())
                .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation(
                    options =>
                    {
                        //options.Enrich = Enrich;
                        options.RecordException = true;
                    })
                .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
                    .AddOtlpExporter(options =>
                    {
                        options.Endpoint = new Uri("http://localhost:4317");
                        //options.ExportProcessorType = ExportProcessorType.Simple;
                    })
                    .AddConsoleExporter(options => options.Targets = ConsoleExporterOutputTargets.Console)
                    .AddInstrumentation<MyTraces>()
                    .AddSource(Measures.InstrumentationName)
                .AddSource("Azure.*")
                .Build();





            // The Service Bus client types are safe to cache and use as a singleton for the lifetime
            // of the application, which is best practice when messages are being published or read
            // regularly.
            //
            // Create the clients that we'll use for sending and processing messages.
            client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
            //sender = client.CreateSender(queueName);
            await Receiver();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to end the application");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }```



============      Message Subscriber Handler Code ========

```        static async Task MessageHandler(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
        {
            ServiceBusReceivedMessage message = args.Message;
            
            ConsoleAppQueueProcessorCounter.Add(1);
            using var activity = _myTraces.Source.StartActivity(); // Can add listeners to activity.Events()
            if (message.ApplicationProperties.TryGetValue("Diagnostic-Id", out var objectId) && objectId is string diagnosticId)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"----- Diagnostic-Id = {diagnosticId}");
                
                activity.SetParentId(diagnosticId);

            }
            activity?.AddEvent(new ActivityEvent("MessageHandler started"));

            activity?.AddTag("ConsoleAppQueueProcessorCounter", "Foo()");

            string body = args.Message.Body.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine($"Received: {body}");

            // complete the message. message is deleted from the queue. 
            await args.CompleteMessageAsync(args.Message);
            activity?.AddEvent(new ActivityEvent("MessageHandler completed"));

        }```
````